# Type check for more than one type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

To type check a variable using `mypy` you can do something like `x:int = 0`.
Is there a way so that i can check for `x` to be type either `str` or `int`.
Can i do something like `x:str or int`?

Comment: Whats wrong with `type(x)`

Comment: Use `typing.Union`.

Comment: @SuperStew type(x) give type of x. I want to type annotation maybe using mypy

Comment: What's wrong with an if/or statement? If type(x) == int or float?

Comment: @Swift what was wrong with type(x) == int that they introduced type annotations in the first place

Comment: Also, isn't `if type(x) is int` valid?

Comment: It's valid. But `isinstance(x, int)` is preferable. It covers subclasses as well. For example `isinstance(True, int)` is true, since bool is a subclass of int.